# collection view cells order changes when loading images from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Currently I am working on an app where different stores showed in a collection view.
I stored the images in Firebase and load them into a collection view. (I have a custom cell with one image view). But somehow every time when I go to the controller where the collection view is in, the order changed and the stores are on other places as they should be.

I had some issues to load the images into the collection view, so I count how many cells I have and then I load the images into the colelctionview cells:

```
FirebaseHelper.sharedInstance.getStoreImages(shoe_ID: shoe_ID!) { (data, storeImage) in
    self.data.append(data)
    if self.data.count == self.countLoadedImages {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let width = collectionView.frame.width / 2
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DetailCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailCollectionViewCell
    
    
    cell.roundedView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width - 5 , height: width - 5)
    cell.storeImageImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: width - 60, height: width - 60)
    
    if !data.isEmpty {
        cell.storeImageImageView.image = UIImage(data: data[indexPath.row])
    }
    
    
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    

    if selectedRows[indexPath.row] == false {
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 4
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        countLoadedImages += 1
    } else {
        cell.layer.borderColor = Colors.darkGreen.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 4
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        countLoadedImages += 1
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

**Here I load the images from Firebase:**

```
func getStoreImages(shoe_ID: String, completion: @escaping(Data, String) -> Void) {
    
    let DATABASE_STORAGE_REF = DATABASE_STORAGE.reference()
    
    self.DATABASE_REF.child("websites").child(shoe_ID).queryOrderedByValue().observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        
        guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
        
        let newModel = StoreModel(dictionary: dic, key: snapshot.key)
        
        let storeImage = newModel.storeImage!
        print("storeImage", storeImage)
        
        DATABASE_STORAGE_REF.child("\(shoe_ID)/\(storeImage).png").getData(maxSize: .max) { (data, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                completion(data!, storeImage)
            }
        }
    }
 
            
}
```

Comment: Hello, is the issue: that the stores appear in a different order every time the collection-view loads or are the wrong images loaded for the stores.

Comment: Can you explain what that Firebase code is doing and include a snippet of your Firebase structure (as text please, NO images). It's really not clear what you're trying to do there as your loading data within */websites/shoe_ID* orderedByValue which orders it by the value of the node, each node being read one at a time, but what's the expected result there since it's not even a query - are you meaning to load all data?. Also, .childAdded leaves an observer on */websites/shoe_ID* is that intentional?

Comment: What the firebase code does is to load a image from the Firebase storage. I pass a unique ID through the parameter where I can get the different store image which is assigned to the associated id. I want to sort all images that I am getting back. But everytime the images are in a different order.

Comment: Again, it would be helpful to see your Firebase structure. Also, I was really asking how `getStoreImages` is called as if you're passing data in a random order, it will retrieve images in a random order